# show more and slice dynamic div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slice, show-hide

I have dynamic div displayed, then in click show more display the rest by 2. In my case, the button show more display one time by the slice, How I can change it to display such as we have posts by slice 2 .All works , just , the slice work one time after the first display then become not functional . My goal is to display posts by slice and such us we have posts , we do show more

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.show-less').hide();
    $(".show-more").click(function() {
        $('.show-block').toggleClass('show-block hide-block').toggle();
        $(this).prev().find('.hide-block').slice(0, 2).toggleClass('hide-block show-block').css({
            "display": "block",
            visibility: 'visible'
        });
        $('.show-less').show();
    });
    $(".show-less").click(function() {
        $('.show-block').toggleClass('show-block hide-block').toggle();

        $('.show-more').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });

});

 <?php
                    $custom_terms = get_terms('genre');
            
                    foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
                        wp_reset_query();
                        $postsPerPage = -1;
                        $current_category = "";
            
                        $args = [
                            'post_type' => 'film',
                            'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
                            'orderby' => 'id',
                            'order' => 'ASC',
            
            
                            'tax_query' => [
                                [
                                    'taxonomy' => 'genre',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            
                                ],
                            ],
                        ];
            
                        $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                        $parent_included = false;
                        if ($loop->have_posts()) {
                                          echo '<h2 class="text-actualites">' . $custom_term->name . '</h2>';
            
                            $counter = 0;
                            //$count_posts = count($loop->have_posts());
                            $i = 0;
            
                            while ($loop->have_posts()) :
            
                                $loop->the_post();
            
                                $i++;
            
                                $img = get_field('image', "$post->ID");
            
                                $cat = $custom_term->term_id;
                                $current_category = $cat;
            
                                if ($custom_term->name == "Adventure") {
                                ?>
            
                                 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                     <div class="card1 recrutements">
                                         <div class="card-header">
                                             <div>
                                                 <img src=<?php echo $img["url"]; ?> class='mymap-icon' alt=''>
            
                                             </div>
            
            
                                             <div>
                                                 <span class="titre-recrutement">
                                                     <div class="bnt-makers ">Communiqué de presse </div>
                                                     <div> <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>
            
            
                                                     <div class="bnt-maker "><?php the_field('nom', $post->ID); ?>
                                                     </div>
            
                                             </div>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="card-body">
                                             <p><?php the_field('description', $post->ID); ?> </p>
            
                                             <a class="dedcription-btn pop recrut" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                                                 <span class="name-descripeion">En savoir plus</span>
                                                 <div class="btn-icon">
                                                     <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                                 </div>
                                             </a>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
            
            
                                <?php
                                } else {
                                    $counter++; 
                                    if (!$parent_included) {
                                       echo '<div id="parentId">';
                                     
                                       $parent_included = true;
                                    }
                                    
                            ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-16 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" class="content">
                                     <?php
                                        if ($counter <= 2) {
                                            echo ("<div class='card recrutements'>");
                                        } else {
                                            echo ("<div class='card recrutements hide-block'  id='$cat'>");
                                            //var_dump($cat); data-id='$cat'
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                     <div class="card-header">
                                         <div>
                                             <img src=<?php echo $img["url"]; ?> class='mymap-icon' alt=''>
            
                                         </div>
                                         <div>
                                             <span>
                                                 <div><?php echo '<p>' . $custom_term->name . '</p>'; ?>
                                                 </div>
            
                                                 <div> <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></div>
            
                                                 <div class="bnt-maker "><?php the_field('nom', $post->ID); ?>
                                                 </div>
            
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="card-body">
                                         <p><?php the_field('description', $post->ID); ?> </p>
            
                                         <a class="dedcription-btn pop recrut" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
                                             <span class="name-descripeion">En savoir plus</span>
                                             <div class="btn-icon">
                                                 <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                             </div>
                                         </a>
                                     </div>
                                    </div>
             </div>
            
            
             <?php
                                }
                            endwhile;
                            echo('</div>');
                        }
                       
                        if ($custom_term->count > 2) {
                           
                            echo ("<div class='show-more' data-id='$current_category'>Show more</div>");
                            
            
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi ! What about a piece of html, to visually understand your goal ? :)

Comment: Note that `toggle()` changes the inline `style` attribute from `display: none` to `display: block` (or whatever jQuery feels is appropriate) and back. It's rare to see both `toggleClass` and `toggle` used on the same element, since one would normally include the `display` property in the CSS class one is toggling, rather than toggling it separately.

Comment: We can't added slice() to toogle () ?

Comment: Sometimes you better go to the HTML, Inspect Element and copy the generated Outer HTML, not paste some PHP which we have nothing to do with in a question asking for JavaScript support.

Comment: Also, do you know what `$('.show-less').show();` means? Now take a look where you use it.

Comment: `.toggleClass('hide-block show-block')` is an overkill. You need only one default stylesheet and only one *special className* that you'll toggle using JS. Not two.

Comment: I used this $('.show-less').show(); to display button show less after the click show more

Comment: Thank you for your remarks , but I don’t find solution to display posts with some specific conditions